# Need some explanation in python arrays

Tags: c#, python

I am converting a python algorithm to c#, and I need some explanation. So I have this list of lists:

```
offsets2 = [[(0.1, 0.1), (0.5, 0.1), (0.9, 0.1), (1.1, 0.1)],
            [(0.1, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5), (0.9, 0.5), (1.1, 0.5)],
            [(0.1, 0.9), (0.5, 0.9), (0.9, 0.9), (1.1, 0.9)],
            [(0.1, 1.0), (0.5, 1.0), (0.9, 1.0), (1.1, 1.0)]]
```

and this:

```
for offset in offsets2:
    offset = [(int(x + lane.width * dx), 
               int(y + self.canvas.row_height * dy))
              for dx, dy in offset]
```

and I am wondering what dx and dy are? I am guessing it's delta x and delta y, but just want to make sure, and also ask how to get them in c#.

Comment: Question doesn't seem very useful to me. Read about list comprehensions.

Comment: This code looks slightly broken to me. The assignment `offset = ...` does not change the *content* of the list but only the `offset` variable. Everything that has been calculated in one iteration is dropped at the beginning of the next iteration. Only the result of the last iteration is available via `offset` which is probably not what you want. In order to change the content of a list use `offset[:] = ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code uses a so called [`List Comprehension`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

It roughly translates to:

```
for offset in offsets2:
    _tmp = []
    for dx, dy in offset:
        _tmp.append((int(x + lane.width * dx), 
                     int(y + self.canvas.row_height * dy))
    offset = _tmp
```

The `offset` contains 2-tuples and the expression `for dx, dy in offset` unpacks those while iterating over it. It is the same as writing:

```
for coord in offset:
    if len(coord) != 2:
        raise ValueError
    dx = coord[0]
    dy = coord[1]
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put print statement to find out what you want.

```
for offset in offsets2:
    print offset
    tmp = []
    for dx, dy in offset:# for each pair (dx,dy) of offset
        print dx, dy
        newCoords = (int(x + lane.width * dx), 
               int(y + self.canvas.row_height * dy))
        tmp.append(newCoords)
    offset = tmp[:]

>>> [(0.1, 0.1), (0.5, 0.1), (0.9, 0.1), (1.1, 0.1)]
>>> 0.1, 0.1
>>> 0.5, 0.1
>>> 0.9, 0.1
....
>>> [(0.1, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5), (0.9, 0.5), (1.1, 0.5)]
>>> 0.1, 0.5
>>> 0.5, 0.5
>>> 0.9, 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

`dx` and `dy` are just temp variables which are allocated to each set of values in the list. So in the first iteration, `dx=0.1, dy=0.1`, in the second, `dx=0.5, dy=0.1`, and so on.